# RDS - Aurora Serverless - is that possible to Migrate from Aurora Serverless to Aurora Provisioned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Say I am running Aurora serverless cluster(MySql). If in case I need to go back to Aurora Provisioned (MySql), is this possible to migrate?

Comment: serverless v2 or v1?

Comment: posted a solution, idid it helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clear cut approach mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2-administration.html#aurora-serverless-v2-converting-to-provisioned)

- Modify writer instance by selecting and choosing modify instance configuration to anything other than **serverless**